# ¿Por qué no puedo acceder a una propiedad de la clase de mi pagina desde el .aspx?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

Hola amigos tengo un problema, tengo una base de datos donde guardo las rutas de imagenes y quiero recuperarlas y mostrarlas en un documento `aspx`, trato de  agregar las rutas a un `listof` y tambien pasarlas a una propiedad publica )esto pasar la ruta al atributo `src` de una etiqueta `<img src.../>`)  que eh creado pero me sale un error de

> img no es miembro de asp.default_aspx

(img es la propiedad que cree), no se que tengo mal necesito su ayuda

```
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader
        Dim rutasImg As New List(Of Imagenes)
        Dim cn As String
        cn = "Data Source=DRACO-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Usuarios; User Id=sa;Password=xxx"

        Dim conexion As New SqlConnection(cn)

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        cmd.Connection = conexion
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT* FROM usuarios"
        conexion.Open()
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()


        While dr.Read()
            Dim ruta As New Imagenes

            ruta.img = dr.Item("Imagen")
            rutasImg.Add(ruta)
        End While
        conexion.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="fonix._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="muestra"></div>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>        
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />        
    </div>        
    </form>
    <img src="<%=Me.img%>" />
</body>
</html>
```

clase que contiene la propiedad img

```
    Public Class Imagenes
    Public Property img As String
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder acceder a la lista de imagenes primero deberias exponer una propiedad pública en la página, o sea

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Public Imagenes As New List(Of Imagenes)

  'resto codigo

End Class
```

Entonces dentro del evento del boton deberías cargar esa lista

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

     'resto del codigo

     While dr.Read()
        Dim ruta As New Imagenes

        ruta.img = dr.Item("Imagen")
        Me.Imagenes.Add(ruta)
     End While

End Sub
```

Cada item que agregas lo añades a la lista que define la propiedad publica, por eso se usa `Me.Imagenes.Add(ruta)` cuando iteras los datos. Luego en el html defines

```
<%For Each item As imagenes In Me.Imagenes%>
   <img src="<%=item.img%>" />
<%Next%>
```

De esta forma crearas la lista de imagenes, ya que tienes acceso a la propiedad publica de la página que expone la lista de imagenes para ser accedida desde el html

Nota: puede que debas definir algun `Imports` en el html para tener acceso al namespace de la clase que has declarado